# Javascript Performance Improvements

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm currently fighting with Internet Explorer's (IE7) javascript performance issues, and struggling to find good information on improving performance, whether it be for a specific browser or in general.

I think it will be helpful to all of us to have a link/tips/hints collection on improving JavaScript performance. Feel free to post what you think will be helpful to the community!

Some links to start:

- [IE & JavaScript Performance Recommendations, MSDN (Part 1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/08/28/728654.aspx)
- [IE & JavaScript Performance Recommendations, MSDN (Part 2)](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/11/16/ie-javascript-performance-recommendations-part-2-javascript-code-inefficiencies.aspx)
- [IE & JavaScript Performance Recommendations, MSDN (Part 3)](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2007/01/04/ie-jscript-performance-recommendations-part-3-javascript-code-inefficiencies.aspx)
- [Benchmark - W3C DOM vs.
  innerHTML](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html) (Shows IE bad performance on DOM)

Enjoy -- I hope this will be helpful to many developers to come. Please post especially the niche tricks you found out about after chewing on a problem for hours. They're the ones most likely not well documented yet & the most exciting ones!

Answer (score 1):

By far the best information I've ever seen on low-level improvements that are applicable to all javascript code:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU

It's a Google Tech Talk from one of their engineers who definitely knows his stuff. It's well-worth the time to watch!

Answer (score 0):

http://ejohn.org/blog/

I find John's blog incredibly insightful. Would it be from a performance or general design point of view.